# Javascript array + index

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Im still needing help with this, and have edited the jsfiddle post to show my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/7ztEf/6/

I want to return number to associated index value [0] =0 [1]=1 as you can see the index string returns all numbers. Thanks again Paul

I have a number generator script that returns values to DIV ID's. I need to hook into this somehow, to enable replacing color based upon the number value i.e. `> 1 && <= 20 = red` etc.

```
function myNumbers(numbers, type) {
    for (var x in numbers) {
       document.getElementById(type + x).innerHTML = numbers[x];
    } 
}
```

This script fills each of the DIVs named `num0` ... `num3` with a random number.

I have managed to query the first value of `numbers[x]` but need to set an index order to loop through the rest, or something.

Comment: what is numbers? is it an array or object

Comment: Your code seems fine, Can you check this demo and tell what is the desired o/p http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7ztEf/

Comment: You should not use `for..in` with arrays, it will iterate over all enumerable properties (including inherited properties), not just numeric indices. Also, order isn't guaranteed (but that probably isn't an issue here). Use a normal `for` loop with incrementing index, or `forEach` with a shim for older browsers.

Comment: Hi thanks Johny, using the jsfiddle you posted I am wanting to query the value of myNumbers, if value is 1 then div bg =blue, if value is two bg =red etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.forEach`.

```
numbers.forEach(function (number, index) {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for..in` for arrays. They're meant to be used on objects so using `for..in` on arrays will return such things as the `length` element.

Either use forEach as ethagnawl mentioned or use the traditional `for` loop:

```
for (var x=0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
   document.getElementById(type + x).innerHTML = numbers[x];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @slebetman! This still returns [0] = 0,1,2,3. I need to list index [0][1][2] and the numbers value. Cheers P

Comment: Very close. There are still things you're misunderstanding. I just changed a few characters in you code to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/h9AS6/1/

Comment: Read the differences between my jsfiddle and yours carefully.

Comment: Thanks again @slebetman that has helped me, now I can access the array index. Could you recommend how I should compare the returned index values? ie for each index[0][1][2][3] if myNumbers == 1 than do something else if myNumbers ==2 do something. JS is not my thing so appreciate any help!!! cheeers P

Comment: `numbers[x]` is the value `x` is the key and `numbers` is the array. So just do `if(numbers[x] == 1) ...` etc

Comment: Wanted to say thanks @slebetman for you posts! just doing if(numbers[x] == 1) returns index 0 query accross all index 0,1,2,3. This was where it all began for me and why started down the for each in index approach. Ive gone full circle and so re posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352734/array-index-n-o-value